# How to create python bindings for a glib/gobject based library

Tags: python, binding, glib, gobject, pygobject

I would like to create Python3 bindings for a glib/gobject based library, namely [infinote/libinfinity](http://git.0x539.de/?p=infinote.git;a=summary).

I am a bit puzzled about the necessary steps to accomplish this. Does [PyGObject](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject) help here or not? Is [this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-wrap/) still valid for python3 and PyGObject?
If not, what do I need to read to understand how this will work?
Are there any tools to (semi-)automate the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need GObject Introspection. [Here](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection) is an overview page, and [here](http://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/AutotoolsIntegration) are instructions on how to integrate it into your project if you use Autotools (which I see you do.)

That's really all you need. Say you name your introspection repository `Infinity-1.0.gir`. Then, after building and installing, all you need to do in Python is

```
from gi.repository import Infinity
```

And presto, your library is now usable from Python.

(PS. The guide you linked to is outdated.)